# jQuery .load() breaks PHP variables loaded into html body

Tags: php, jquery, html

So I have an interesting problem

I am having issues with the jquery .load() function. I have a file structure as follows

```
index.php  
|  
|---header.html  
|---body.html  
|---footer.html
```

index.php sets three variables as so `$variable_one = new Database('passedQuery');`

header.html, body.html and footer.html are then included into index.php

In body.html I have something similar to

```
<div class="span4 well">
        <h3>Current Statistics</h3>
        <hr>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Users</th>
                    <th>Event One</th>
                    <th>Event Two</th>
                    <th>Event Three</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $var1->result[0][0]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $var2->result[0][0]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $var3->result[0][0]; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I also have a form in body.html which is submitted through a generic jquery function as so

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        var vals = $(form).serialize();
        var form_id = $(form).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            type: $(form).attr('method'),
            data: vals,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Success");
                $('#information').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Great Success! :)</div>');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#content').load('views/partials/body.html');
                }, 5000);
            },
            error: function(a, b, c){
                console.log("Error");
                $('#information').html('<div class="alert alert-error">Epic Failure</div>');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#content').load('views/partials/body.html');
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

When I submit the form and reload the body the PHP variables that were echo'd in the html are now gone and I get an apache error similar to the following

```
[dateTime] [error] [client IP] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: variable in /path/to/body.html on line 133, referer: myReferrer
```

I asked a few of my friends about this and they were all stumped, as was #jquery of Freenode. Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE - FORM CODE AND index.php CODE**
*Form*

```
<div class="span4 well">
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="admin_add" name="admin_add" method="post" action="routes/to/add_admin.php">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Add Administrator</legend>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="select03">Select a user</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select id="select03" name="user">
                            <?php
                                foreach($var1->result as $key => $value)
                                    echo "<option>".$value[0]."</option>";
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-submit-button">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

*Index*

```
$var2 = new Database('query', 'SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM attendees WHERE eid = 1');
$var3 = new Database('query', 'SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM attendees WHERE eid = 2');

/**
 * List users to add to database
 */
$var1 = new Database('query', 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE admin=0');

/**
 * Include all the visuals
 */
include('views/partials/header.html');
require_once('views/partials/body.html');
include('views/partials/footer.html');
```

Comment: can you post your form code aswell

Comment: What's line 133 In body.html?

Comment: @DaveM it simply refers to where I echo a variable, you can see in my updated example

Comment: Shoudn't it be $var1->result()?

Comment: One thing, don't use `.html` with files that include php code. If you want to differentiate template/html files you can use `.phtml` or my favourite is `.tpl.php`. This is for many reasons but the main ones are 1. not all servers "see" `.html` as being able to parse php too, if you migrate/someone else uses your code they might get into trouble. 2. If I'm maintaining code and trying to find php in there the last place I'm going to look is a `.html` file. That's confusing. :)

Comment: +1@ThomasClayson - Putting PHP in .html files isn't too great from a maintainability point of view.

Comment: @DaveM no because result is a public variable in the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load body.html the first time I guess that you're loading it using php's `include()` function. Well, what this does is "concatenate" the php so on the server side it's like its one long php file. This works with your variables because its as if there is no break in the code.

When you use jQuery's `load()` functions this happens client side. What is happening is that you're getting the html output of JUST `body.html` and you are dynamically (on the client side) putting that content into the client's page.

The problem you're having then is that the PHP is no longer concatenated. `load()` takes `body.html` in its singularity and puts it into the page.

Another way to look at it is that when someone goes to `index.php` the php is parsed, all the variables that are echo'd are turned into bog standard text/html and shipped to the browser. Once there they are no longer php variables, they are just text/html. Making a new request to `body.html` via javascript means that those variables you're referencing are no longer available. They've already been converted to HTML and shipped to the browser, then the php stopped, and this is a new request.

I don't know how you want to fix this to be honest. You might want to look into a templating system like smarty. Or you might want to put your functions into a file called `functions.php` include it into your `body.html` and then reference those functions in your `body.html` rather than relying on code in the index page.

i.e. your `body.html` will look like this:

```
<?php include "functions.php"; ?>
<div ...>
<?php 
    $var1 = getVar1(); // function in functions.php
    echo $var1->result[0][0];
    // ... etc
?>
</div>
```

Then when it is called from javascript, before it is delivered to the browser, the php will be evaluated and everything will work.

Hope I've explained this well dude. :)

Comment: Trying that implementation didn't seem to work for me. I have issues with paths to my database class. I was wondering I I took your advice with naming them *.tpl.php and then do a require_once() on the files will this stop the massive mashing together of files and still achieve the same result?

Comment: I think you need to rethink your whole structure of your app. For instance in your case you have index.php which has (for example) `text text text <?php include "body.html"; ?> text text text" right? If you go to index.php you see "text text text contents of body.html text text text". If you go to body.html you will only see "contents of body.html". So if the contents of body.html rely on information coming from index.php, calling body.html on its own will fail (in the way you've found).

Comment: So the way round this is not to rely DOWN the heirarchy of files. i.e. body.html shouldn't rely on being called from WITHIN another file. body.html should call OUT of itself for the information it needs. This is where the idea of a functions.php file comes in. If you need someone's username in body.html, put `function getUsername(){ return "Thomas Clayson"; }` in functions.php. Then you need to reference OUT to functions.php from body.html `include "functions.php"`. Then further down in body.html you can call `echo getUsername()`.

Comment: I hope that makes sense. :) One reason why you are having problems is that you're using body.html as an `include()d` script AS WELL as a stand-alone file ajax'd in (using `load()`) on the client side. You should separate these two really. One way you can do this is to create body.html again, but with its own logic inside it (the same logic that is in index.php) and call this instead from jquery. Using a functions.php file in this instance reduces the amount of duplicated code.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. If it works I shall virtually kiss you. Thank you good sir, you have shown me the light :)

Answer (score 0):

When your jQuery request gets to the server it will be serving you back body.html, which doesn't have any PHP processing, so your variables set within index.php, don't exist.